# Optimization and multithreading

Tags: qt

In my Qt6 C++ program, a loop loop performs a very large number of iterations and I don't know how to optimize it in time. Is it possible to somehow optimize the code or implement multithreading of the loop?

```
complex<double> PrepQFT(int a, int b, int c, int d, int m) {
    const double pi = acos(-1);
    complex<double> result = exp(complex<double>(0.0, (-2.0 * pi * (a * c + b * d) / m)));
    return result;
}

void QFT(int g, int x, int p, int m, int U, vector<int>& X, vector<int>& Y) {
    vector<vector<complex<double>>> QFT_arr(m, vector<complex<double>>(m, complex<double>(0.0, 0.0)));

    vector<vector<double>> absQFT_arr(m, vector<double>(m));

    for (int C = 0; C < m; C++) {
        for (int D = 0; D < m; D++) {
            for (int A = 0; A < m; A++) {
                for (int B = 0; B < m; B++) {
                    if (mod(fast_pow_mod(g, A, p) * fast_pow_mod(x, B, p), p) == U) {
                        QFT_arr[C][D] = QFT_arr[C][D] + PrepQFT(A, B, C, D, m);
                    }
                    else {
                        QFT_arr[C][D] = QFT_arr[C][D] + 0.0;
                    }

                }
            }
            absQFT_arr[C][D] = (1.0 / sqrt(m) * abs(QFT_arr[C][D]));

            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what to use to somehow speed up this cycle...

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Qt?

Comment: You can of course run the whole function within a separate thread. That of course doesn't make it run any faster, it just allows you to do other things while you're waiting. Since you're using Qt, read about QThread [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html). When the function is done you will need to emit a signal to alert the main thread.

Comment: Your loops are nested in such a way it executes the `if (mod(fast_pow_mod(g, A, p) * fast_pow_mod(x, B, p), p) == U)` test `m^4` times (note: I have been squinting on the code in `else` but it looks like it effectively does nothing). Has you nested them in order `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` you could have moved it up the nest in order to execute it only `m^2`, and with better branch prediction down the line. You would need to place the line `absQFT_arr[C][D] = (1.0 / sqrt(m) * abs(QFT_arr[C][D]));` should be placed in a separate nested loop with only `C, D`

Comment: Following my previous comment, some context i.e. **NOT** just code, would be useful for us to think of shortcuts you could take without having to decipher your code. The article [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) does say you should *introduce the problem before you post any code* and ***Don't just skip straight to the code!*** Example: I think but am not sure you are trying to sum elements of the form `e^(2πi*<variable>/<constant>)` (please confirm), in which case there may be a pattern turning many partial sums into 0, i.e. potential to skip loops.

Comment: You are also strongly invited to share your expected output for a few given inputs, as well as your actual output if different, so that we can test your and our own code against it.